# Angular API Call doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, get

Here is my code. I'm trying to display a list when a property is selected from a combobox. I'm getting the list from backend, but I get this error whenever I click the display button. Even though, the method is a `GET` method. What could be the problem?

[image]

TS:

```
filter() {
    this._stockService
      .getWarehouseTransferReport()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>
          this.filterPredicate(data, filter);
      });
  }


  filterPredicate(data: IWarehouseTransferItem, filter: string) {
    let searchText = data.Reference;
    if (data.Reference) {
      searchText += (data.Reference as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
  }
    if (data.DeliveryNote) {
        searchText += (data.DeliveryNote as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
    }
    if (data.StockIntegrationCode ) {
        searchText += (data.StockIntegrationCode  as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
    }
    if (data.Product.ProductName) {
        searchText += (data.Product.ProductName as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
    }

    return searchText.indexOf(filter) >= 0;
}
```

Service TS:

```
getWarehouseTransferReport(): Observable<IWarehouseTransferItem[]> {
    return this._http.get("Stock/GetWarehouseTransferReport");
}
```

Backend C#:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// TRANSFER REPORT
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="producdId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public List<DtoWarehouseTransferItem> GetWarehouseTransferReport(int producdId)
        {
            return WarehouseSpProvider.GetWarehouseTransferReport(producdId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to call the `GetWarehouseTransferReport` API with Postman and see the result?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that server know the method but the target source is not supported. Here is the reference [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).
So basically it is not Angular Http client problem to be precise.

Reference link which shows many details on 405 status code problem. [Link](https://kinsta.com/blog/405-method-not-allowed-error/)

Answer (score 0):

Your C# Backend code requires a parameter **int productId** but I think you are not passing any parameter that's why it is now being called.

Answer (score 0):

- May be you are passing wrong object or object mismatches the value.
- may be datatype issue or parameter count issue and your API needs
  proper object and value.